# Новый главный экран в приложении на Java

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток!

Я только начинаю изучать мобильную разработку под андроид на Java и у меня возник вопрос, ответ на который я не смогла найти в интернете (возможно, потому что неправильно формулировала вопрос), но, надеюсь, тут меня кто-нибудь поймет.

В общем, как мне известно, по умолчанию на Java создается класс *MainActivity*, который является главным экраном при запуске приложения. Скажем, если в моем приложении при первой установке появится **главный экран с регистрацией(аутентификацией)**, а после входа в личный кабинет нужно сделать страницу **"личный кабинет" главным экраном** (то есть экраном, который будет сразу загружаться при нажатии на иконку приложения), каким образом это осуществляется?

Или просто подскажите, пожалуйста, как и где можно найти информацию об этом, может, я какие-то вещи неправильно обзываю? И это не главный экран, а точка входа?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы реализовала это по-другому.
Главным `Activity` всегда остаётся личный кабинет, но в нём присутствует проверка на то, выполнен ли вход. Если да - открывается личный кабинет, если нет - переход на страницу регистрации.
Можно каждый раз проверять, выполнен ли вход. Например, если Вы используете Firebase Auth, можно проверять переменную `user`

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    // пользователь вошел в систему, можно ничего не делать, спокойно загружать страницу личного кабинета
} else {
    // пользователь не зарегистрировался/не вошел в систему, нужно открыть Activity страницы регистрации
    finish();
    Intent intent = new Intent(ТекущаяАктивити.this, АктивитиКабинета.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Если у Вас какая-то другая схема входа, то, как вариант, можно хранить информацию о том, выполнен ли вход, используя `SharedPreferences`.
Когда пользователь регистрируется, записывать в переменную значение

```
SharedPreferences mSettings = getSharedPreferences("mysettings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = mSettings.edit();
editor.putBoolean("isLogged", true);
editor.apply();
```

Затем, в главной `Activity` (личном кабинете) делать проверку:

```
SharedPreferences mSettings = getSharedPreferences("mysettings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
if(mSettings.contains("isLogged")) {
    if(!mSettings.getBoolean("isLogged", true)){ // если переменная не равна true, то есть пользователь не зарегистрировался
        finish();
        Intent intent = new Intent(ТекущаяАктивити.this, АктивитиКабинета.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

А в последствии, когда пользователь выйдет из системы, не забудьте обновить переменную и записать в неё `false`.

Answer (score 2):

В файле `AndroidManifest.xml` у главной активности надо поставить такой `<intent-filter>`:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

У активности, которая сейчас является главной этот `<intent-filter>` надо убрать.

Comment: Это только единоразово изменит страницу, с которой будет запускаться приложение. Придется менять код каждый раз, как какой-то пользователь будет входить/выходить из профиля?